# Nombramiento de Arreglos en JAVA

Tags: java, array, espacio-de-nombres

mi probema es el siguiente: Necesito hacer varios arreglos y que en cada uno de estos arreglos tengan nombres, pero no se la cantidad de arreglos asi que use un ciclo for para crear la cantidad que necesite el usuario de arreglos, pero al ser el mismo nombre los datos se sobreescriben, mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de nombrar un arreglo conforme el nombre que agregue la persona de cada amigo??
'''
do {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < cantMainAmigos; i++) { 
            //System.out.println("Digite el nombre de su amigo: "); 
            //String mainNombre = entrada.next();
            //System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de platillos que consume su amigo: ");
            //int mainComida = entrada.nextInt();
            //if (mainComida <=2){
                //String [] mamigo;
            //}   
            String [] mamigo;
            System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de amigos de su amigo que desea agregar: ");
            cantSecAmigos = entrada.nextInt();
            mamigo = new String [cantSecAmigos];
            mainAmigo = mamigo;                
            
            for (int I = 0; I < cantSecAmigos; I++) {
                System.out.println("Digite el nombre del amigo de su amigo: ");                    
                String subNombre = entrada.next(); 
                System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de platillos que consume el amigo de su amigo: ");
                int subComida = entrada.nextInt();
                if (subComida <= 2){
                    mamigo[I] = subNombre;
                }                                 
            }
            
            listaInvitados = Arrays.asList(mamigo);
            System.out.println("Si desea salir del programa presione: 1");
            int salida = entrada.nextInt();
            if (salida == 1){
                break;
            }            
        }
    }while(cont != 0);
```

'''

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código en forma de texto ;)

Comment: Hola, si compartes tu codigo con bloques de codigo en vez de imagenes haces que la comunidad pueda copiar y pega tu problema para encontrar una solucion, a demas de hacer el codigo mas legible

Comment: Necesitas otra estructura de datos. Podría ser un `HashMap<String, String[ ]>`, donde el primer parámetro sería el nombre del pepito y el segundo, el array de amigos. Revisa más sobre Map y List para ver cuál te sirve más y te da la flexibilidad que necesitas. PD. Compartir código como imagen es la forma equivocada de pereza; copiar y pegar el texto es igual de fácil y ayuda a que podamos revisar mejor el código (a ver qué pasa si te responden con una imagen y te ponen a transcribirla)

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es trabajar con arreglos,te serviría un array de array,te comparto un ejemplo que puedes adaptar a tu ejercicio a tu manera,no necesitaría nombrar cada arreglo sino manejar la posición de cada arreglo en el array de array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Amigo{
 
public static void main(String[] args){
 

 System.out.println("Ingresa cantidad de arreglos que necesitas");
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 int cantidad=sc.nextInt();
 int grupo=0;
 String amigos=null;
 String[][]arreglo;
 for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
  System.out.println("cuantos amigos debe tener el grupo "+(i+1));
  grupo=sc.nextInt();
  arreglo=new String[cantidad][grupo];
  for(int j=0;j<arreglo[i].length;j++){
      System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del amigo "+ (j+1));
      amigos=sc.next();
      arreglo[i][j]=amigos;
  }

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglo[i]));
 }


 }
}
```